# Why is the Google App Engine JDBC connection URL not working?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I am developing a Website with a Registration page. I want to store the user details in the table of the MySQL database on Google App Engine. Following is the JDBC connection URL:-

```
Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://google/my_database_name?cloudSqlInstance=my_db_instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=My_Username&password=My_Password&useSSL=false", "root", "My_Password");
```

But this URL isn't working as even after registering, no details are stored in the table of my database. So, do suggest any alternatives. Thank you

The following is the RegistrationServlet code which takes input values from Register.jsp and I want it to store the values into my gcloud db table:-

```
  @WebServlet("/RegistrationServlet")
public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;

 public RegistrationServlet() {
  super();

 }

 @Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {

 }

 @Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {

  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  String first_name = request.getParameter("f1");
  String last_name = request.getParameter("l1");
  String phone = request.getParameter("p1");
  String email = request.getParameter("e1");
  String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
  String user_dob = request.getParameter("udate");
  String password = request.getParameter("pwd");



  UserData ud = new UserData();

  ud.setFirst_name(first_name);
  ud.setLast_name(last_name);
  ud.setUname(uname);
  ud.setPhone(phone);
  ud.setEmail(email);
  ud.setUser_dob(user_dob);
  ud.setPassword(password);

  // validate given input
  if (first_name.isEmpty() || last_name.isEmpty() || phone.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Register.jsp");
   out.println("<font color=red>Please fill all the fields</font>");
   rd.include(request, response);
  } else {
   try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   // loads mysql driver



   try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://google/my_database_name?cloudSqlInstance=my_db_instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=My_Username&password=My_Password&useSSL=false", "root", "My_Password");


    String query = "insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query); //generates sql query



    ps.setString(1, first_name);


    ps.setString(2, last_name);


    ps.setString(3, uname);


    ps.setString(4, phone);


    ps.setString(5, email);


    ps.setString(6, user_dob);


    ps.setString(7, password);



    ps.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println("successfully inserted");



    ps.close();




    con.close();




   } catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   session.setAttribute("username", first_name);
   response.sendRedirect("Success.jsp");



  }
 }
```

Comment: In the URL, the attribute `cloudSqlInstance` has `my_db_instance` as value. Can you confirm the value is the `instance_connection_name` (ex: `<MY-PROJECT>:<INSTANCE-REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>`)? Also, what example are you following to set up the connection? Are you testing it locally? I would suggest to follow the [GCP CloudSQL for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql) connection example with a simple application to test if the connection works

Comment: I have not mentioned my exact database instance here. my_db_instance is just for your reference. Yes, I tested it locally and it works fine there. I am following the official Google Cloud documentation. Thank you, but I am following the documentation from the same source which you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've followed the [GCP CloudSQL for MySQL connection example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql) and it has worked after deployment. I'll go step by step of the process I did so you can compare and see if there's some configuration step missing on your end.

1. Used a MySQL 2nd Gen Cloud SQL instance. This instance is in the **same project** as the Google App Engine I'll deploy the script in
2. Created a new database in the CloudSQL instance
3. Ran the command `gcloud sql instances describe instance1` to get the **instance connection name** in the form of `<MY-PROJECT>:<REGION>:<INSTANCE-NAME>`
4. Downloaded the GCP Java code samples and got to the Java 8 App Engine standard Cloud SQL example:

   `git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples.git`
   `cd java-docs-samples/appengine-java8/cloudsql/`
5. Completed the fields `<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>`, `<user>`, `<password>` and `<database>` from the `POM` file with the connection values for my case. This fields will be used by the `appengine-web.xml` to create the `cloudsql` property that will be used as the **connection URL** by the code in `CloudSqlServlet.java`
6. Also in the `appengine-web.xml`, I changed the `<service>` name to `default`. There's actually no need to change anything on this file but I chose to change the service due to personal preference
7. The [other required dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql#setting-up-sql-instance) where already in the downloaded `POM`
8. Deployed to GAE with `mvn appengine:deploy`

This is a minimal example of a working GAE to Cloud SQL connection for MySQL. Try to follow this steps to test if the connection works poperly with the provided code example.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer but I think, the main problem is with the URL which I've mentioned above. Database setup was successfully done on the gcloud using mysql as I also accessed the database from the terminal. I am having a RegistrationServlet which takes inputs from the Register.jsp page and stores them into the gcloud db. I have edited my above question and have pasted the RegistrationServlet code there. Pls do have a look.

Comment: @ShashankkShekarChaturvedi I used your code in my example and it inserted to the database locally and after the deploy. Can you go more in deep about why do you think the issue is in the URL. Also, you stated that no info is stored in the datastore. There's no error trace in the logs or elsewhere?

Comment: Hi, now I think the problem is not with the URL. My project was not a maven based, but now I have configured it to a maven project. It's working locally but when I deploy it using "clean appengine:deploy", it gives me an error stating that No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups. But, I have already set it up like this:- <plugin> <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId> <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId> <version>1.9.66</version> </plugin> in my pom.xml file. Pls help. Thank you

Comment: Could you please help me with this issue:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707416/unable-to-deploy-maven-project-on-google-app-engine